# Access Token giving different AUD?

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, access-token

I'm trying to authenticate with API Management in Azure through OAuth. I've set up that piece fine.

I've got an OAuth2 Implicit login flow happening where I get an ID Token and Access Token (`response_type=id_token+token`). When I check `aud` in the returned access token, I get the default Graph API aud (00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000) instead of my Client ID, which I need to use to authenticate with the API Management piece.

This needs to stay behind OAuth as it's an internal app, something that I don't want to let loose on the public. I'm using an implicit flow because the webpage is a SPA hosted on Blob.

Comment: If you are getting a Graph access token, then your scope/resource is probably pointing at Graph API. Could you show what you have configured as the scope/resource?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by scope/resource - the URL I'm getting the token from? It looks like:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize/?client_id=<client-id>&response_type=id_token+token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1234%2Fcallback&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state=4275368970&nonce=1642008447

Comment: The scope query parameter in that URL :) Looks like you only specified openid. You should specify in addition a valid scope for your app. You can find and create these in the Expose an API section of the app registration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As junnas said, if you want to get the `aud` of your clientId, you need to add valid scope for your app.

Go to `Expose a scope` of your app registered in azure ad, and `Add a scope`.

[image]

And add the scope in the url like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxx
&response_type=id_token+token
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:123
&scope=openid api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-a3aab90df9fc/webread
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

Then decode the access token, you will get the client id in aud:

[image]